# Not able to understand the notations : * and ** with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference, pointer-to-pointer

I have a problem with the pointers. I know what this does:

```
*name
```

I understand that this is a pointer.

I've been searching but I do neither understand what this one does nor I've found helpful information

```
**name
```

> The context is int **name, not multiplication

Could someone help me?

Comment: pointer to pointer : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointer_to_pointer.htm

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thanks all :)

Comment: It completely depends on the context in which `*name` and `**name` are.

Comment: Well, obviously in `5 * name` it's multiplication. But that is a **binary** (2 arg)  `operator *`, not the **unary** (1 arg) `operator*`.

Comment: @MSalters You're thinking operators, yet the answerers are all thinking types. So, context matters.

Comment: @juanchopanza: For a beginner, the only context that matters is the use of a unary operator versus the use as a binary operator. Because type definition intentionally mirrors use, it doesn't matter here whether we discuss `int **name` or `std::cout << **name`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> *<sup>NOTE: Without the proper context, the usage of `*name` and `**name` is ambiguous. it may portrait (a). dereference operator (b) multiplication operator</sup>*

Considering you're talking about a scenario like

- `char * name;`
- `char **name;`

in the code,

- `*name`

`name` is a pointer to a `char`.

- `**name`

`name` is a pointer, to the pointer to a `char`.

*<sup>Please don't get confused with "double-pointer", which is sometimes used to denote pointer to a pointer but actually supposed to mean a pointer to a double data type variable.</sup>*

A visual below

[image]

As above, we can say

```
char value = `c`;
char *p2 = &value;   // &value is 8000, so p2 == 8000, &p2 == 5000
char **p1 = &p2;     // &p2 == 5000, p1 == 5000
```

So, `p1` here, is a pointer-to-pointer. Hope this make things clear now.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks sir for the advice. Updated accordingly.

Comment: what does "pointer to a type" mean? You can't point to types in C++.

Comment: @Adam I tried generelizing. , data and function combined. Any better word suggestion, please?

Comment: In your first case I'd say "name is a pointer to `char`" and in the second case "name is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`".

Answer (score 8):

It's actually very simple, consider this:

```
int a; // a is an int
int* b; // b is a pointer to an int
int** c; // c is a pointer to a pointer to an int
```

If you see every level as just another variable type (so, see *int as a type), it's easier to understand.
Another example:

```
typedef int* IntPointer;
IntPointer a; // a is an IntPointer
IntPointer* b; // b is a pointer to an IntPointer!
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

pointer stores address of variable, pointer to pointer stores address of another pointer.

```
int var
int *ptr;
int **ptr2;

ptr = &var;
ptr2 = &ptr;

cout << "var : " << var;
cout << "*ptr : " << *ptr;
cout << "**ptr2 : " << **ptr2;
```

You can look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_to_pointer.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = 5;// a is int, a = 5.
int *p1 = &a; // p1 is pointer, p1 point to physical address of a;
int **p2 = &p1; // p2 is pointer of pointer, p2 point to physical adress of p1;

cout<< "a = "<<a << " *p1 = "<<*p1<<" *(*p2) = " << *(*p2)<<endl;
```

Answer (score -2):

**name in this case. Would be a pointer to a pointer.