# struct pointers,too many pointer symbols

Tags: c

Recently, I've been learning algorithms, so I try to code leetcode. There are some programs like

```
int pop(struct node ** top_pt){
//弹出数据并且释放内存
if (*top_pt==NULL){
    printf("stack overflow\n");
    exit(0);
}

struct Node *top=*top_pt;
//满递增
int res=top->val;

*top_pt=top->Next;
free(top);
return res;
```

}

so, what is the difference between the pointers like `*` and `**`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do pointer to pointers work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not able to understand the notations : \* and \*\* with pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692986/not-able-to-understand-the-notations-and-with-pointers)

Comment: 是的呢，最近一直在学习算法，指针那部分看了不少，现在结构体指针又来了。掌握的不扎实呢。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing really, a pointer is a pointer is a pointer, it's how you *use* it that makes all the difference.

This pattern (passing a pointer to a pointer to something) is a ways of emulating *pass by reference* (which C doesn't have) for a pointer. This means that when you change the pointer using e.g. `*top_ptr = top->Next` that change will be in the calling function as well.